# How can I make a Dynamic SSO with multiple idp tenants URLs

Tags: java, single-sign-on, spring-saml

I am using saml2 in spring for my implementation of Single Sign ON, However I need to include a dynamic url in the IDP metadata file so that supports changing tenant ID for multytenancy support: 
https://IDP_URL/{tenantID}/saml/SSO
So how can I manage that on spring saml.